# Can you filter nhibernate sub collection?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have the following nHibernate query that works well for me to pull an entity and eager fetch its sub collections.

```
var contactInfo = session.QueryOver<PeopleInfo>()
                         .Fetch(x => x.Addresses).Eager
                         .Fetch(x => x.EmailAddresses).Eager
                         .Fetch(x => x.PhoneNumbers).Eager
                         .Where(x => x.Id == contactInfoId)
                         .SingleOrDefault();
```

Now, let's say in Addresses that there is a field called Active,
is there a way to just return all the active addresses in one call?

I can filter it out after the fact, I'm just wondering if there's
a way to do it via query over.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but you need to include some joins in your QueryOver query.

Under the hood, `.Fetch` is generating a bunch of `LEFT JOIN`s to bring back the full list of `PeopleInfo` without excluding people that don't have any of the associated collections that you're fetching eagerly.

You can override the way the join is performed by performing a left join yourself.

For example, if you want to get all `PeopleInfo`, and only addresses that are `Active`, you could do the following:

```
Address addressAlias;

var addressRestriction = Restrictions.Where(() => address.Active);

session.QueryOver<PeopleInfo>()
    .Left.JoinQueryOver(
        pi => pi.Addresses, () => addressAlias, addressRestriction)
    .Fetch(x => x.Addresses).Eager
    .Fetch(x => x.EmailAddresses).Eager
    .Fetch(x => x.PhoneNumbers).Eager
    .Where(x => x.Id == contactInfoId)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Now, since you're `JOIN`ing on `Address` and selecting out the entire `PeopleInfo` entity, you don't actually need to use `.Fetch` to pull back all of the `Address` fields.

```
session.QueryOver<PeopleInfo>()
    .Left.JoinQueryOver(
        x => x.Addresses, () => addressAlias, addressRestriction)
    .Fetch(x => x.EmailAddresses).Eager
    .Fetch(x => x.PhoneNumbers).Eager
    .Where(x => x.Id == contactInfoId)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

The `Address` columns are included in the `SELECT` clause because you've joined on `Address` and are selecting out the entire `PeopleInfo` class.

These both generate the same SQL, but you should verify in a profiler. It should look something like this:

```sql
SELECT this_.*         -- All PeopleInfo columns
       addressali1_.*, -- All Address columns 
       emailaddre4_.*  -- All email address columns
FROM   PeopleInfo this_ 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN address addressali1_ 
                    ON this_.id = addressali1_.personid 
                       AND ( addressali1_.active = 1) 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN emailaddress emailaddre4_ 
                    ON this_.id = emailaddre4_.personid 
WHERE  this_.id = <your id>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info about fetching being a left join ... i ended up using JoinAlias instead of JoinQueryOver so that I can do the filtering for multiple sub collections. Also a question - should I do left outer join instead of left join for empty set to be returned?

Comment: @aggietech: `LEFT OUTER` and `LEFT` joins are the same (`OUTER` is optional)